# AES Encrypt and Decrypt between C# and PHP MCrypt

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, encryption

I seem to be having problems getting an AES256 string to decode between a PHP and .NET application. I get an error in the .Net application stating "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." This error fires in the using statement for the CrytoStream. The workflow is pretty straight forward. The PHP application encrypts a value and passes it to the .NET application as a URL parameter. The .NET application needs to decrypt that value for later use. The .NET method works from .NET to .NET, but PHP to .NET is the problem.

The PHP code:

```
   function encrypt($text) {
    $key = "M2AZULUALPHA";
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $padding = $block - (strlen($text) % $block);
    $text .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 'TripBuilder2017');
    return base64_encode($crypttext);
 }
```

The .NET Decrypt method:

```
    private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "M2AZULUALPHA";
        byte[] saltArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TripBuilder2017");

        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, saltArray);
            encryptor.KeySize = 256;
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I changed the mode in PHP to Rijndael256 and I also changed AES to RijndaelManaged in .NET. Again, I am able to get this working between .NET applications, but not with the PHP application. I am wondering if there is an issue with the padding the PHP application is using.

Comment: For mcrypt "Rijndael256" is not AES, the 256 refers to the block size and AES only has one block size: 128-bits. Probably what you may want is AES with a 256-bit key size although a 128-bit key size is essentially as secure as a 256-bit size.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I updated answer completely after messages :-)

php:

```
function encrypt($text) 
    {

    //$key = "M2AZULUALPHA"; //  type 2 -- mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 12 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported -- at line 7
    $key = "M2AZULUALPHA1234";
    //$vi ='TripBuilder2017'; // type 2 -- mcrypt_encrypt(): Received initialization vector of size 15, but size 16 is required for this encryption mode -- at line 9
    $vi ='TripBuilder20170';
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $padding = $block - (strlen($text) % $block);
    $text .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
    $crypttext = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $vi));
    return $crypttext;
    }

    $result = encrypt("abcdcddsfdafdfe");
    echo"$result";
```

output is "pPPH8amRhqbdX6D83jr74A=="

c# with `RijndaelManaged`

```
public String Decrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            var result = "";
            var cypher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            var Key = encoding.GetBytes("M2AZULUALPHA1234");
            var IV = encoding.GetBytes("TripBuilder20170"); 
            using (var rj = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rj.KeySize = 256;
                rj.Key = Key;
                rj.IV = IV;
                var ms = new MemoryStream(cypher);
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

test:

```
var result = Decrypt("pPPH8amRhqbdX6D83jr74A==");
Debug.WriteLine(result);
```

output is "abcdcddsfdafdfe"

Comment: hitting the bulls eye here +1.

Comment: I added the cipher mode, but changing the Blocksize to 256 is generating an error stating "Specified block size is not valid for this algorithm."

Comment: Why not use RijndaelManaged?

Comment: I just tried that with the same result. Works from .NET to .NET, but not from PHP to .NET

Comment: @ChrisLombardi AES only has one block size: 128-bits.

Comment: @levent Changing the block size to 256-bits makes the encryption Rijndael, not AES and the OP specifies AES. It is best to use AES, not Rijndael with a 256-block size.

Comment: @zaph Thank you. I am going to try something other than MCrypt to see if we get a better result. Since the application works flawlessly using AES or Rijndael256 between .NET applications I am thinking it has to do with how MCrypt is padding.

Comment: @ChrisLombardi Consider using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), it supports several platforms so it good fro cross platform encryption. It also adds key derivation, authentication and versioning all "for free".